# Why are these MongoDB queries using indexes differently?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-3.0

I've been trying to diagnose some long running queries and whilst profiling them I've noticed some very strange behaviour that I can't explain (pun intended); which I'm hoping someone here can...

Given an abridged example document of:

```
{
    author: "laura",
    keywords: ["foo", "bar", "hello"],
    created_date: ISODate("2017-01-18T00:00:00Z"),
    type: "content"
    ...
}
```

And indexes of:

```
{type: 1, author: 1, created_date: -1}
{type: 1, keywords: 1, created_date: -1}
```

If I run the following query:

```
db.items.explain().find({$or: [
    {
       type: "content", 
       author: "kate", 
       created_date: {
         $lte: ISODate("2017-01-25T00:00:00Z"), 
         $gte: ISODate("2017-01-18T00:00:00Z")
       }
    },{
       type: "article", 
       keyword: "bar", 
       created_date: {
         $lte: ISODate("2017-01-25T00:00:00Z"), 
         $gte: ISODate("2017-01-18T00:00:00Z")
       }
    }
]})
```

In the executionPlans, I notice that for the `author` component of the query, the entire query scans the index:

```
    {
            "stage" : "IXSCAN",
            ...
            "keyPattern" : {
                "type" : 1,
                "author" : 1,
                "created_date" : -1
            },
            ...
            "indexBounds" : {
                "type" : [
                    "[\"content\", \"content\"]"
                ],
                "author" : [
                    "[\"kate\", \"kate\"]"
                ],
                "created_date" : [
                    "[new Date(1485388799000), new Date(1484697600000)]"
                ]
            }
        }
```

Where as the `keywords` query splits the date out into a fetch stage as well:

```
{
        "stage" : "FETCH",
        "filter" : {
            "created_date" : {
                "$gte" : ISODate("2017-01-18T00:00:00Z")
            }
        },
        ...
        "inputStage" : {
            "stage" : "IXSCAN",
            ...
            "keyPattern" : {
                "type" : 1,
                "keywords" : 1,
                "created_date" : -1
            },
            ...
            "indexBounds" : {
                "type" : [
                    "[\"article\", \"article\"]"
                ],
                "keywords" : [
                    "[\"bar\", \"bar\"]"
                ],
                "created_date" : [
                    "[new Date(1485388799000), true)"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
```

I know that when indexing on a list/array field, a document is created for each element in that field so wonder if it's a product of that, but it's strikes me as bizarre that this is the behaviour.

Any thoughts would be gratefully recieved